# How to set permissions for a CIFS mount with autofs?

Tags: centos, mount, cifs, chmod, autofs

I've set up a CIFS mount on my CentOS 6.4 server with autofs :

*File /etc/auto.mnt :*

```
Photos -fstype=cifs,perm,rw,uid=505,forceuid,gid=505,forcegid,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,credentials=/root/credentials.txt ://adsrv01/Photos
```

What a `ls` command shows :

```
[root@websrv01 mnt]# ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Apr 26 12:01 Photos
```

What I expect from the `ls` command :

```
[root@websrv01 mnt]# ls -l
total 4
drwxrwx--- 1 photos photos 4096 Apr 26 12:01 Photos
```

Do you see anything wrong ? How can I set owner and chmod right ?

Edit : I forgot to say that chown and chmod commands are denied for root user on the /mnt/Photos directory. I can't get it right, and I also tried using fstab.

This is what happens with fstab :

```
mkdir /mnt/Photos
chmod 770 /mnt/Photos
chown photos:photos /mnt/Photos
mount /mnt/Photos
```

The permissions are automatically changed and set to 755 when the directory is mounted. I can't set the mode back to 770 : permission denied.

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer : you have to use the option `nounix` together with `file_mode` and `dir_mode`

Here is my fstab :

```
//adsrv01/Photos      /mnt/Photos           cifs    credentials=/root/credentials.txt,file_mode=0770,dir_mode=0770,nounix,uid=505,gid=505 0 0
```

Comment: fstab is not autofs...

Answer (score 0):

I've been just able to get a sane working setup, partly thanks to your answer @mimipc, but I'm sharing here a more complete description.

My rPI is called `malinovka.daonet.home` in my `/etc/fstab`.  On both server and client, I have `netvor` user, and I want to use a single share from the client to both read and write to a single share.

To export the share from the *malinovka* rpi, I've added this section to the *smb.conf*:

```
[netvorovo]
   comment = netvorovo
   public = no
   writeable = yes
   browsable = yes
   path = /path/to/netvorovo
   create mask = 0644
   directory mask = 0755
```

and "created user" (that is, even if the `netvor` user is already created, I need to "create" it again for samba):

```
smbpasswd -a netvor
```

(I've just generated strong password that is only used for samba).

On the client, I have three files under */etc/auto.master.d*:

- *malinovka.autofs*:

  ```
  /-  /etc/auto.master.d/malinovka.map --timeout=300
  ```
- *malinovka.map*:

  ```
  /mnt/netvorovo    -fstype=cifs,credentials=/etc/auto.master.d/malinovka.credentials,uid=9860,gid=9860,file_mode=0640,dir_mode=0750,nounix ://malinovka.daonet.home/netvorovo
  ```
- and *malinovka.credentials*:

  ```
  username=netvor
  password=(redacted)
  ```

At this point, logged in as `netvor`, I can just create files/dirs on /mnt/netvorovo and the default modes are as usual.

Comment: I just tried adding this to my working `autofs.direct` entry but it made no difference: `,uid=9860,gid=9860,file_mode=0640,dir_mode=0750,nounix`

Comment: Silly me - I forgot to run `sudo service autofs restart`. Now it works. I can enjoy proper dir_colors now, not non-executable files being bold and flourescent.